# overridePendingTransition not working on certain device

Tags: android

So i have this code for animation on back pressed

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
    }
```

left_to_right.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

right_to_left.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

And i've tested this code on two devices :

1) **Nexus 7 with 4.0.4 API** : everything is ok

2) **Samsung GT-S55660 with 2.3.6 API** : *NO ANIMATION APPEARS*

**Please help with no animation bug**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to turn on animation in device settings